# Fix android studio warning about `layout_marginHorizontal`

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-version

I'm getting these warnings in my android build.

```
Warning:(19, 9) Attribute `layout_marginVertical` is only used in API level 26 and higher (current min is 24)
Warning:(20, 9) Attribute `layout_marginHorizontal` is only used in API level 26 and higher (current min is 24)
```

Clearly our app's layouts make use of `layout_marginVertical` and `layout_marginHorizontal` attributes, which were introduced in API level 26. The warning makes it sound like these attributes won't work on level 24 devices, but indeed they work perfectly. I would like to understand why I'm getting these warnings, despite there seeming to be nothing wrong.

One obvious solution is to use the "longhand": `marginTop` and `marginBottom` instead of `marginVertical`, but I'm hoping to continue to use these "short" parameters if possible, to improve readability and reduce repetition.

Were these attributes undocumented for level 24? Or is there some kind of backward compatibility at play? If so, why the warning?

We are using:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="24"
    android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
```

---

**Update:** Setting `targetSdkVersion="24"` seems to fix the warnings, and the desired margins continue to work. This solves my immediate problem, but I'm left confused about why a level 26 feature works on level 24, and why targeting level 26 causes warnings. What do I do if I want to target level 26?

Comment: Did you find out why your `layout_marginHorizontal ` worked on pre-26 devices? I have the same "problem" now. Actually, `layout_marginHorizontal` even works on Android 4.4

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev Nope, sorry - never got around to figuring this one out. Let me know if you do!

Comment: @aaaidan I don't think lowering your `targetSdkVersion` is recommended. To my understanding:
`android:minSdkVersion="min_sdk_version_required_to_install_the_app"`
`android:targetSdkVersion="sdk_version_that_the_app_works_well"`
`android:buildSdkVersion="latest_sdk_available"`.

As you mentioned, `android:layout_marginVertical` still works with some magic. But if you want to get rid of the warning without lowering the `targetVersion`, you can use `tools:targetApi="26"` or `tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"` to suppress the warning.

Comment: @MaksimDmitriev The reason for it working is AAPT https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/tools/aapt2/readme.md#version-2_16

Answer (score 3):

Works via AAPT2 since version [2.16](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/tools/aapt2/#version-2_16). Here is the [confirmation](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/e2crzv/comment/f8xp0f5).
But you should be careful, it works only in layout files. It will not work in styles files, [even when there is no warning](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/145362255).

Answer (score 1):

This API seems to be introduced in API level 26. 
Since you might be using AppCompatActivity, maybe they have also introduced some backward compatibility for pre 26 SDK. [image: Documentation]

Moreover, the warning that you are receiving might just be a lint check error.